# Which characters need to be escaped in HTML?

Tags: html, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters

Are they the same as XML, perhaps plus the space one (`&nbsp;`)?

I've found some huge lists of HTML escape characters but I don't think they **must** be escaped. I want to know what **needs** to be escaped.

Comment: I feel like there should be a native function for this. We have encodeURI() for this exact purpose for URL strings. We need the same thing for string of characters in quotes in HTML maybe encodeHTML() or encodeQuotes()? In my case I need to put a value in the alt tag. `<img alt="value here">`. Having HTML in that place breaks the element.

Answer (score 505, accepted):

If you're inserting text content in your document in a location where text content is expected<sup>1</sup>, [you typically only need to escape the same characters as you would in XML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#use). Inside of an element, this just includes the entity escape ampersand `&` and the element delimiter less-than and greater-than signs `<` `>`:

```
& becomes &amp;
< becomes &lt;
> becomes &gt;
```

Inside of attribute values you must also escape the quote character you're using:

```
" becomes &quot;
' becomes &#39;
```

In some cases it may be safe to skip escaping some of these characters, but I encourage you to escape all five in all cases to reduce the chance of making a mistake.

If your document encoding does not support all of the characters that you're using, such as if you're trying to use emoji in an ASCII-encoded document, you also need to escape those. Most documents these days are encoded using the fully Unicode-supporting UTF-8 encoding where this won't be necessary.

In general, you should not escape spaces as `&nbsp;`. `&nbsp;` is not a normal space, it's a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). You can use these instead of normal spaces to prevent a line break from being inserted between two words, or to  insert          extra        space       without     it     being     automatically       collapsed, but this is usually a rare case. Don't do this unless you have a design constraint that requires it.

---

<sup>1</sup> By "a location where text content is expected", I mean inside of an element or quoted attribute value where normal parsing rules apply. For example: `<p>HERE</p>` or `<p title="HERE">...</p>`. What I wrote above **does not apply** to content that has special parsing rules or meaning, such as inside of a script or style tag, or as an element or attribute name. For example: `<NOT-HERE>...</NOT-HERE>`, `<script>NOT-HERE</script>`, `<style>NOT-HERE</style>`, or `<p NOT-HERE="...">...</p>`.

In these contexts, the rules are more complicated and it's much easier to introduce a security vulnerability. **I strongly discourage you from ever inserting dynamic content in any of these locations.** I have seen teams of competent security-aware developers introduce vulnerabilities by assuming that they had encoded these values correctly, but missing an edge case. There's usually a safer alternative, such as putting the dynamic value in an attribute and then handling it with JavaScript.

If you must, please read [the Open Web Application Security Project's XSS Prevention Rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules) to help understand some of the concerns you will need to keep in mind.

Comment: Some HTML attribute values may also have special meaning (JS/CSS). So it also doesn't apply to these, for example: `<p onclick="NOT-HERE">...</p>` and `<p style="NOT-HERE">...</p>`.

Comment: Note that the order of replacement is important.  You must replace `&` first.  This is obvious but is an easy mistake to make.  So your code should look something like this: `displayTitle = title.replaceAll('&', '&amp').replaceAll('<', '&lt').replaceAll('>', '&gt;').replaceAll("'", '&#39;').replaceAll('"', '&quot;');`

Comment: @tst Here is an update to add semicolons: `displayTitle = title.replaceAll('&', '&amp;').replaceAll('<', '&lt;').replaceAll('>', '&gt;').replaceAll("'", '&#39;').replaceAll('"', '&quot;');`

Answer (score 22):

It depends upon the context. Some possible contexts in HTML:

- document body
- inside common attributes
- inside script tags
- inside style tags
- several more!

See OWASP's [Cross Site Scripting Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html), especially the "[Why Can't I Just HTML Entity Encode Untrusted Data?](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#why-cant-i-just-html-entity-encode-untrusted-data)" and "[XSS Prevention Rules](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#xss-prevention-rules)" sections. However, it's best to read the whole document.

Answer (score 14):

Basically, there are **three main characters** which should be always escaped in your HTML and XML files, so they don't interact with the rest of the markups, so as you probably expect, two of them gonna be the syntax wrappers, which are <>, they are listed as below:

```
 1)  &lt; (<)
    
 2)  &gt; (>)
    
 3)  &amp; (&)
```

Also we may use double-quote (") as " and the single quote (') as &apos

Avoid putting dynamic content in `<script>` and `<style>`.These rules are not for applied for them. For example, if you have to include JSON in a , replace < with \x3c, the U+2028 character with \u2028, and U+2029 with \u2029 after JSON serialisation.)

HTML Escape Characters: Complete List:
http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

So you need to escape <, or & when followed by anything that could begin a character reference. Also The rule on ampersands is the only such rule for quoted attributes, as the matching quotation mark is the only thing that will terminate one. But if you don’t want to terminate the attribute value there, escape the quotation mark.

> **Changing to UTF-8 means re-saving your file:** 
> Using the character encoding UTF-8 for your page means that you can avoid the need for
> most escapes and just work with characters. Note, however, that to
> change the encoding of your document, it is not enough to just change
> the encoding declaration at the top of the page or on the server. You
> need to re-save your document in that encoding. For help understanding
> how to do that with your application read Setting encoding in web
> authoring applications.
>
> **Invisible or ambiguous characters:**
>
> A particularly useful role for escapes is to represent characters that
> are invisible or ambiguous in presentation.
>
> One example would be Unicode character U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK. This
> character can be used to clarify directionality in bidirectional text
> (eg. when using the Arabic or Hebrew scripts). It has no graphic form,
> however, so it is difficult to see where these characters are in the
> text, and if they are lost or forgotten they could create unexpected
> results during later editing. Using ‏ (or its numeric character
> reference equivalent ‏) instead makes it very easy to spot
> these characters.
>
> An example of an ambiguous character is U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE. This
> type of space prevents line breaking, but it looks just like any other
> space when used as a character. Using   makes it
> quite clear where such spaces appear in the text.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to escape a string of markup using JavaScript there is:

- https://github.com/component/escape-html

or, if you don't want to pull in a dependency, here is the same thing, though slightly slower because it uses `split/map/join` instead of `charCodeAt/substring`.

```js
function escapeMarkup (dangerousInput) {
  const dangerousString = String(dangerousInput);
  const matchHtmlRegExp = /["'&<>]/;
  const match = matchHtmlRegExp.exec(dangerousString);
  if (!match) {
    return dangerousInput;
  }

  const encodedSymbolMap = {
    '"': '&quot;',
    '\'': '&#39;',
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;'
  };
  const dangerousCharacters = dangerousString.split('');
  const safeCharacters = dangerousCharacters.map(function (character) {
    return encodedSymbolMap[character] || character;
  });
  const safeString = safeCharacters.join('');
  return safeString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer depends on the context. In general, these characters must not be present ([HTML 5.2 §3.2.4.2.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/dom.html#text-content)):

> Text nodes and attribute values must consist of Unicode characters, must not contain U+0000 characters, must not contain permanently undefined  Unicode characters (noncharacters), and must not contain control characters other than space characters. This specification includes extra constraints on the exact value of Text nodes and attribute values depending on their precise context.
>
> For elements in HTML, the constraints of the Text content model also depends on the kind of element. For instance, an "<" inside a textarea element does not need to be escaped in HTML because textarea is an escapable raw text element.

These restrictions are scattered across the specification. E.g., attribute values ([§8.1.2.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#attribute-values)) must not contain an [ambiguous ampersand](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#ambiguous-ampersand) and be either *(i)* empty, *(ii)* within single quotes (and thus must not contain U+0027 APOSTROPHE character `'`), *(iii)* within double quotes (must not contain  U+0022 QUOTATION MARK character `"`), or *(iv)* unquoted — with the following restrictions:

> ... must not contain any literal space characters, any U+0022 QUOTATION MARK characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), U+003D EQUALS SIGN characters (=), U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN characters (<), U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN characters (>), or U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT characters (`), and must not be the empty string.