# Is it necessary to html encode right angle brackets?

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

I'm adding some meta description data to my header like so:

```
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name = "description";
meta.Content = description; // this is unencoded
page.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

And .net helpfully encodes things like & and <, but not >.  Now, I can't imagine that this would be an oversight, so I conclude that it's unnecessary to escape them.  But before I go back to the client with that answer, it would be nice to get confirmation by Some Strangers From The Intarwebs first :)

Comment: this is duplicate question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html was first — no matter is it asp or whatever was used to generate the (H)TML spec is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue) `>` is indeed valid for attributes. Only `<`, `&` and `"` or `'` need escaping.

```
[10]    AttValue    ::=    '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'
                         | "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
```

Comment: Interesting.  It appears that .net is **not** escaping "'".

Comment: .Net 4.0 test : `meta.Content = "&<>\"'";` -> `content="&amp;&lt;>&quot;&#39;"`

Comment: Hm.  Maybe I'm confused, or what I think is an "'" is actually something else.  At any rate, my first question was answered. Thank you, Knowledgeable Stranger from the Internet!