# Do Angle Brackets Need to be HTML-Escaped in Nested Style Elements?

Tags: html, css

Suppose you have the following in your HTML document:

```
<style>
  ul.foo > li {
    /* etc */
  }
</style>
```

Is it valid syntax to HTML-escape the greater-than child selector as `$gt;`?

```
<style>
  ul.foo &gt; li {
    /* etc */
  }
</style>
```

I understand it's [not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462348/right-angle-bracket-in-html), but is it good form?

Comment: I would say no, because it's not being rendered as HTML.

Comment: If you ever decide to move this to a separate stylesheet you'll have to refactor your css, which seems like a bad idea to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's valid HTML, but not valid CSS, because the embedded stylesheet isn't parsed as HTML at all; it's parsed as CSS, meaning that the `&gt;` is seen literally. `&gt;` is not a valid selector, and therefore it's not valid CSS.

This is only true of HTML; in XHTML, it *is* valid and browsers *will* decode the `&gt;` into `>` before parsing the stylesheet as CSS. The following data URI demonstrates this:

```html
data:application/xhtml+xml,<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><style>ul.foo&gt;li{color:red}</style></head><body><ul class="foo"><li>Foo</li></ul></body></html>
```

Just like in HTML, though, it's not necessary in this specific context, for the reason given in the question you link to, but it's still considered well-formed XHTML. But generally, putting embedded scripts and stylesheets into CDATA sections is preferred over encoding every single `<`, `>` and `&`:

```
<style>
/* <![CDATA[ */
  ul.foo > li {
    /* etc */
  }
/* ]]> */
</style>
```