# HTML tag to preserve angular brackets

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular

`<pre>` tag helps to preserve spaces and line brakes in HTML. But I've a text with angular brackets like -

```
<some text here>
```

and I want that to appear on web page as it. But if I've this text in html, it is not shown on the page.

Is there any HTML tag which is used to enclose the text will help to preserve angular brackets?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right angle bracket in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462348/right-angle-bracket-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
&gt; to make >
```

and

```
&lt; to make <
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if works:

```
<xmp>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</xmp>
```

Or you can use &lt; for  "<" and,
&gt; for ">"

Comment: although not wrong, xmp is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp)