# Do I really need to use ascii codes in html for & < > % etc

Tags: html, css, ascii

The question is quite simple and is one of those "always felt too stupid to ask" questions. I am writing out a lot of equations at the moment into tables and dutifully using...

```
     "N/mm&sup2; &gt; 5&#37;" etc
```

and wondering why on Earth we do this? I was taught to and always have but it seems that the plain text (bar the superscript of course) of %, & and > etc etc render just fine in all browsers. Is this just to avoid conflicting with markup and inline scripts etc or is there another reason when just using pure html/css?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters need to be escaped on HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html)

Comment: So, there are three characters you need to escape, and two you need to escape in attributes (sometimes).  If you don't save your file as UTF-8, you need to escape all except about 200 characters.

Comment: It is not a duplicate since I obviously know which characters need to be escaped - I am instead asking WHY we escape them since it appears to make no actual difference to the rendering in any browser I have tested - Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE, Opera.

Comment: `I was taught to` Yes, perhaps from when utf-8 wasn't so prevalent? Like you, I don't see any point these days.

Comment: Best not to be lazy and rely on how things are. That sort of thinking is what's left us with loads of companies stuck using super-old IE versions. Don't be the guy everybody hates in 20 years' time.

Comment: (also I really like the first comment on this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3493405/1180785)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example case, none of the `&` notations is needed, by the specifications or in practice. You can write

```
N/mm² > 5%
```

(as far as HTML goes; as a notation of physics, it is inappropriate).

If you do not know how to enter “²” on your keyboard (or how to copy and paste it), or if your document’s character encoding does not allow it to appear as such, then you need to use an `&` notation for it.

HTML specifications differ in their requirements on using the the `&` notations, but none of them requires any other character than `<` and `&` to be escaped ever, except for `"` and `'` in rare case when they appear inside an attribute value and that sama character is used around the value as a delimiter (it should then be obvious *why* it must be “escaped”).

And in practice, `<` and `&` need to be escaped only when they would otherwise be parsed as part of markup or in the rare situation where you are using genuine XHTML (i.e., XHTML served with an XML media type), in which case their occurrence would be a well-formedness error and would cause a browser to display an error message and refuse to display the document at all.

For example, `a < b` is OK by HTML syntax rules (not XHTML) and to browsers, but `a<b` would be parsed so that `<b` would be taken as starting a `<b>` tag, causing great confusion. Even `a<z` would mess things up, since `<z` would still be parsed as start of tag, due to the way browsers parse HTML, even though there is currently no tag name in HTML that starts with `z`.

Comment: Thank you - a brilliant explanation

Answer (score -1):

You don't *have* to, as most major browsers parse these characters how they are, but it can also cause issues later on in your code. As a side note, some browsers require you use these.

I would use ASCII codes if I were you.

Comment: Could you give a couple of quick examples to explain how it would cause a code issue or browsers that do require them?