# Javascript encode HTML entities on server

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform, html-entities

In my server application (on Parse Cloud Code), I want save some string data. There are HTML entities here, which I want to encode.

So i find a solution with Javascript:

```
var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
txt.innerHTML = html;
return txt.value;
```

This code work perfectly on html pages, where `document` exists. But there isn't such variable on server.

How can i declare document variable? Or maybe you know another solutions for encoding HTML entities.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which characters need to be escaped on HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html)

Comment: Look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html.  There are only a handful of characters that normally need to be escaped and those can be handled with a few `<string>.replace()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked this question, I learned JavaScript and AJAX. So, my suggestion will be using AJAX and JSON for communication between browser and server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [html-entities](https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities) on Node, install it like:

```
npm install html-entities
```

then you got `entities.encode(..)` and `entities.decode(..)` functions:

```
var Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
entities = new Entities();
console.log(entities.encode('<>"\'&©®')); // &lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp;©®
```

there are more examples in [usage](https://github.com/mdevils/node-html-entities#usage) part on gihub repo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function encode(r){
return r.replace(/[\x26\x0A\<>'"]/g,function(r){return"&#"+r.charCodeAt(0)+";"})
}

test.value=encode('How to encode\nonly html tags &<>\'" nice & fast!');

/*************
* \x26 is &ampersand (it has to be first),
* \x0A is newline,
*************/
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows=11 cols=55>www.WHAK.com</textarea>
```