# unescape in javascript not working when %26 ( & sign) is in value

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the below code in my JSP.  UI displays every character correctly other than **"&"**.

```
<c:out value="<script>var escapedData=unescape('${column}');
$('div').html(escapedData);</script>" escapeXml="false" />  </div>
```

E.g. 1) working case

input =   `ni!er@`

Value in my `escapedData` variable is **`ni%21er%40`**. Now when I put it in my `div` using 
`$('div').html(escapedData);` then o/p on html is **as expected**

E.g. 2) Issue case

input = `nice&`

Value in my `escapedData` variable is `nice%26`. Now when I put it in my `div` using 
`$('div').html(escapedData);` then also it displays below

`$('#test20').html('nice%26');`

**However,** when output is displayed in JSP, it just prints **"nice"**. It **truncates** everything after `&`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `unescape` is being phased out. Try using `decodeURIComponent` instead.

Comment: Should it display `nice%26` or `nice&` on the page?

Comment: it should display nice&

Comment: i think it is decodeURI in javascript...trying it now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some misunderstandings what `unescape(val)`/`escape(val)` do and where you need them. And what you need to take attention of when you use `.html()`.

*HTML* and *URI* have certain character that have special meanings. The most important ones are:

**HTML**: `<`, `>`, `&`

**URI**: `/`,`?`,`%`,`&`

If you want to use one of those characters in *HTML*  or *URI*  you need to escape them.

The escaping for [*URI*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3608791/1960455)  and for [*HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382028/1960455)  are different.

The functions [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)/[`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) (deprecated) and [`decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)/[`endcodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) are for *URI*. But was you want is to escape your data into the *HTML* format.

There is no build-in function in_JS_ that does this but you could e.g. use the code of the answer to this question [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234804/1960455).

But as it seems that you use jQuery you could think of just using [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) as this will do the escaping for you.

**An additional note:**
I'm pretty sure that the `var escapedData=unescape('${column}');` does not do anything. I assume that `${column}` already is `ni!er@`/`nice&`.

So please check your source code. If `var escapedData=unescape('${column}');`  will look like  `var escapedData=unescape('ni!er@');` then you should remove the `unescape` otherwise you would not get the expected result if the `${column}` contains something like e.g. `%23`.

Comment: thanks for really good explanation. Will check it and let you know