# Wordpress - Wrong char visualization after no change

Tags: wordpress

I have the following problem on my website: I've made no change, but yesterday all the special chars on all posts became wrong: for example `<` now is `&lt;`. 
If I open the post by admin, in "visual editing" mode, all the chars are correct.

May someone help me to solve, please?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:  after some tests, the problems seems to be related only to the text between `<pre>` `</pre>` tags.

Comment: Have you specified a `charset` in your document?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Yes, I' have "define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');" in my wp-config.php file. But my problem is that all worked fine since yesterday; now is wrong but I've made no change...

Comment: I'm talking about in the *header.php* of your site. Have you added `<meta charset="UTF-8">`?

Comment: Yes, I've that tag in the header.

Comment: Sounds to me like WordPress has corrected your HTML for you. If these characters look OK in visual editing mode, then they will look OK in the web page. I don't see any problem here. ([More information here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html))

Comment: I've made some test and the problem is related only to the text between <pre></pre> tags.

Answer (score 0):

From the [WordPress Codex on the <pre> tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts#Using_the_.3Cpre.3E_tag):

> The `<pre>` tag instructs the browser to use a monospaced font, but to exactly reproduce whatever is inside of the  tags. Every space, line break, every bit of code is exactly reproduced.

Comment: Yes, but I had no problem about that since yesterday. Now I have a misalignment amongst visual editinh, html editing and rendering on page.