# Some characters don't appear properly in code tags

Tags: html, wordpress

so my problem is that symbols like '>'an '&' appear as their respective character codes in the code tag. I have tried typing them out manually and then adding the tag, the other way around as well and it didn't help. 
So what should I do so that '>' appears as the symbol when in the code tag?

Comment: Don't really follow your question, but maybe you are looking for &gt;?

Comment: Also use `&amp;`. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this table](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm). Some characters have HTML codes as they have special meanings if typed as they are. You should use their HTML names (which you can see in the referenced table) in order for them to be rendered correctly.