# Why should I use &amp; instead of &?

Tags: javascript, html, url, encoding, symbols

why should I use `&amp;` instead of `&` when writing HTML for my site?

Where can I find a list of other symbols that I should be encoding? (the bar / too, right?)

What problems could I have if I paste the symbol right as it is into the html?

**The thing is**, I have a few affiliate links and I'm worried that, if I write them with the & in some cases, for some reasons, because of the specific browser or device... that the info in the url wouldn't be passed correctly.

Hopefully someone can clear my mind?

Thanks!

Comment: `"that the info in the url wouldn't be passed correctly"` - What does HTML have to do with URLs?  Do you have an actual example of what you're talking about?

Comment: If you have `&` in a url, that is fine, however, in the code of a page, you'll want to use `&amp;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which characters need to be escaped on HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html)

Comment: @user5900604: Depends on what the `&` is doing in that URL.  It has a specific meaning in that context.

Comment: @Il Magnus you can't be using &amp; in a URL. &amp; is only used in the markup.

Comment: @David you're right, i should have elaborated more.  See these 2 examples: example.com/link.php?affiliateid=123`&`click=456 vs example.com/link.php?title=smith+`&amp;`+myers

Comment: @user5900604: Yes, the second example is entirely invalid and won't produce the expected behavior.

Answer (score 19):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity

> HTML has a set of four reserved characters that must be represented as
>   entities. All other characters can be represented with entities as
>   needed, but it is not mandatory. These are the entities used for those
>   four reserved characters :
>
> - `&amp;` (&) - Required, so that a browser does not misinterpret it as the beginning of an entity.
> - `&lt;` (<) - Required because otherwise a browser could misinterpret it as the beginning of a tag
> - `&gt;` (>) - Required because otherwise a browser could misinterpret it as the ending of a tag
> - `&quot;` (") - Required only within attributes value surrender by quote sign

See here for a full list of all HTML character entities - https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 2):

The character '&' is reserved word which has special purpose. That's why you have to use it in specific way.

Here you can find the HTML Entities. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp