# How to use tags with special characters in htmltools inside rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, htmltools

In a rmarkdown document, how may I use HTML special characters inside a tag with htmltools package?

If we write in a r chunk of a rmarkdown document something like this

```
htmltools::tags$th("&mu;")
```

we get:

```
<th>&amp;mu;</th>
```

instead of

```
<th>&mu;</th>
```

Comment: In addition to my answer below, you might want to read this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367945/why-should-i-use-amp-instead-of . I don't know much on this topic, but just be sure you don't really need the `amp` part of the output afterall.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just work around it like this?

```
gsub("amp", "", htmltools::tags$th("&mu;"))
```

> ```
> <th>&mu;</th>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The `htmltools` package has a function `HTML` for this:

```
require(htmltools)
require(magrittr)

"&mu;" %>% HTML %>% (tags$th) %>% as.character %>% cat
```

Which results in :

```html
<th>&mu;</th>
```