# React DOM escapes any values not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a project using create-react-app my class code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let x='&'
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, {x}edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in output I am expecting & because of [Which characters need to be escaped on HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html) as stated & becomes `&amp;` but getting & instead, as stated in [**official react document**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks):

> By default, React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before
>   rendering them

But in my case this escaping is not working, can anyone please explain why??

Comment: It automatically escape the & before rendering, what is not working here ? Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1fyvyg2/1/)

Comment: "To get started, &edit src/App.js and save to reload. " instead of this i am expecting "To get started, &amp;edit src/App.js and save to reload. ".because of escaping .