# How to stop overwriting previous strings pushed into an array?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to push all the derivation of the sentence.

For example: `The < animal > in the < object >`

I want derivations to hold the expansions, so `derivation[0]` would have `"The cat in the < object >"`, while `derivation[1]` would have `"The cat in the hat"`.

However, all the derivations before getting overwritten by the final derivation.

How do I prevent this from happening?

```
while is_non_terminal?(sentence)
 $key = sentence.match(/(\<[a-zA-Z0-9_\-*]+\>)/)
 sentence.sub!(/(\<[a-zA-Z0-9_\-*]+\>)/){grammar[$key.to_s].sample.join(' ')}
 derivations.push(sentence)
 puts derivations.to_s
 #puts sentence
end
```

Comment: simple fix would be to change `derivations.push(sentence)` to `derivations.push(sentence.dup)` - this will push a copy of `sentence` at its present state to your `derivations` collection.

Comment: Remember `$` is a **global** variable in Ruby and should not be used casually like this.

Answer (score 2):

You only have one string in your code, and your continually modifying it and pushing new references to it into an array. Each entry in your array is simply a reference to the *same* string.

You should use `sub` instead of `sub!` to return a modified copy of your string that you can push into the array, so that each iteration of the loop produces a new string instead of modifying the same string.

Comment: when I do sub instead of sub! it messes everything up

Comment: @msc: "it messes everything up" - unfortunately, this tells us nothing.

Comment: it tries to derive my sentence but goes on an infinite loop. With sub! it derives it just fine

Comment: is there another way to accomplish this

Comment: @msc: Have you considered investigating what _exactly_ causes infinite loop? You _know_ it's a bug/flaw in your code, right?

Comment: I fixed it. I just did String.new within the parameters

Comment: @SergioTulentsev quick question...how would I print something like "<object>" to an HTML....it prints in the terminal but on the web page it just doesn't show up at all

Comment: @msc: it does, check page source.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right! it says <p>["The <object> <verb> tonight."]. However, on the page, it just says ["The tonight"]...is there a way to make it show up?

Comment: @msc: yes there is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-on-html

Answer (score 0):

A more Ruby way of tackling this is:

```
def subst(template, vars)
  template = template.dup
  derivations = [ ]

  while (template.sub!(/\<([a-zA-Z0-9_\-*]+)\>/) { vars[$1].sample })
    derivations << template.dup
  end

  derivations
end
```

Where that can work when called like:

```
subst("The <animal> in the <object>", 'animal' => [ 'cat' ], 'object' => [ 'hat' ]);
# => ["The cat in the <object>", "The cat in the hat"]
```

Note that this can go into an infinite loop if one of your substitutions contains text like `<animal>` which contains text like `<animal>` which contains text like `<animal>`...