# How do I add a <script> tag as a simple string without it being treated as a regular <script> tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, email, email-templates

I'm creating an email template that sends the user some JavaScript code that he needs to place on his website.

I've tried wrapping it in a code tag but it still treats the script tag as an actual tag instead of a string.

```
<p>
    <code>
      <script>
          !function(e,t,i){var n,d=e.getElementsByTagName("head") 
           eElement("script")).id=i,n.setAttribute("key","kKQ1Yxgxm")
      </script>
    </code> 
</p>
```

Expected result is it should treat whatever is in the code tag as a simple string. Including the  tag. But it's being treated as a script tag and not as a plain string.

Comment: Have you tried the <pre></pre> tag yet?

Comment: Just send with the tag brackets as HTML entities, HTML in email is extremely fussy & necessarily paranoid.

Comment: You don't want a script tag, you want something that looks like a script tag, for example `&lt;script&gt;`

Comment: Note that HTML parsing is extra cautious with `script` tags than with others. For example, using `console.log('</script>');` will end your script, even in a string, while it's not the case for other tags.. probably for security reasons

Comment: `<pre>` and `<code>` tags etc. aren't going to help. You need to [**escape**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) your HTML. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` and `&amp;` to escape `<`, `>` and `&` [in the very least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382028/215042).

Answer (score 4):

Escaping the < > should work.

```
 &lt;script&gt;
          !function(e,t,i){var n,d=e.getElementsByTagName("head") 
            eElement("script")).id=i,n.setAttribute("key","kKQ1Yxgxm")
 &lt;/script&gt;
```