# How can Javascript code be displayed as plain text in the body of an HTML email?

Tags: javascript, email, html-email

I have an email that gets sent which outputs the text of HTTP error responses. If the response ever includes Javascript code in `<script>` tags (and some HTML code) then the Gmail (and many other email clients) strip out the code.

Also, if there is anything after the `</script>` that seems to get stripped out as well.

How can I make it so that the Javascript code is not stripped out and just gets included as plain text in the body of an HTML email?

Comment: You could try replacing all the `<` with `&lt;`

Comment: so encode it as plain text

Comment: `<pre>` and `<code>` tags are available

Comment: `<\script>` should be `</script>`. That's why everything after it gets stripped, you didn't properly end the script.

Comment: Why are you trying to send HTML mail with JavaScript in the first place? I don't think any mail clients will execute it.

Comment: HTTP error responses should never contain any HTML tags. You should just encode everything -- in PHP use `htmlentities()`.

Comment: Taplar is on the right track, but there's more to it than that. Not sure how much more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html has some answers, but I haven't read it thoroughly. My guess is you should escape `<` to `&lt;`, `>` to `&gt;` and `&` to `&amp;`. (But escape the `&`s first, otherwise it will go `<` -> `&lt;` -> `&amp;lt;`, which will be displayed as `&lt;`.) I think you can safely ignore where that link mentions contexts such as script tags - there won't be any `<script>` tags because there won't be any `<` characters left.

Comment: @Taplar That worked, thank you.

Comment: @Barmar This is for a response I'm getting from an external API which I have no control over. Normally I get text-only responses from the API but recently I've been getting ones that start with Javascript code. Also, I wasn't trying to execute the code, I just wanted to see what it was and the only way I can be notified of it was through email. It turns out it was related to the New Relic Browser software on the API server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use HTML entities

```
&#x3C;script&#x3E;code&#x3C;/script&#x3E;
```

or

```
&lt;script&gt;code&lt;/script&gt;
```

should become

```
<script>code</script>
```

when rendered

You can use [this tool](https://mothereff.in/html-entities#%3Cscript%3Ecode%3C%2Fscript%3E)