# HttpServletRequest XML string parameter loses HTML Entities in POST action

Tags: java, html, xml, spring, servlets

I have an issue reading an XML string parameter from the request body.

Giving the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<body>

<form action="http://localhost:8080/action" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="TEST" value="<test>mytest</test>"/>    
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the following `@PostMapping` action:

```
@PostMapping
public void action(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String context = request.getParameter("TEST");
    System.out.println(context);
}
```

In the ouput console I have `mytest` instead of `<test>mytest</test>`

The String is losing its Html entities.

What's missing?

Comment: Try escaping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html

Comment: I have tried with value="&lt;test&gt;mytest&lt;/test&gt;" but I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Jsoup dependency that was the cause of the issue.
Jsoup removes every tag that's not defined in a proper Whitelist.