How can I insert unescaped text node into XmlElement?
I'd like to dynamically add style information to a HTML page using the .NET XmlDocument/XmlElement objects.
But whenever I add a text node with content like this: table.songsTable > colGroup > col.genreCol the result is getting escaped as table &gt; colGroup &gt; col.genreCol.
How can I add CSS text to an XmlElement without the contents getting escaped?
Here's a PowerShell sample MRE:
[XmlElement]$style = $html.CreateElement('style')
[XmlText]$text = $html.CreateTextNode(@'

table > colGroup > col.genreCol
{
  display: none;
}

'@ + "`t`t")

$style.AppendChild($text) | Out-Null


It's supposed to be escaped, it's not valid if it's not escaped. Are you seeing an issue where the browser is not parsing it? On a side note, the newer XElement and XDocument are more flexible.

I can't use the other objects without much ado as [XmlDocument] is the DOM behind the PowerShell [XML] data type. — I need the unescaped value, otherwise it's invalid CSS.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381974/which-characters-need-to-be-escaped-in-html correct HTML would have > and < escaped. The parser in the browser will unescape it before using it. Note that not every valid HTML is valid XML, you should really use HTMLAgilityPack instead for this.
